# Wood around stove pipe

Tags: wood, stove

I am thinking about closing the hole that you see on the picture below using wood. The metal sheet will be screwed onto the wood "frame" that I would be building. Is it safe to use wood? The stove pipe never gets too hot, I can touch it with my bare hands but I'm still a little bit concerned.

The wood won't touch the pipe, only the metal sheet will.

[image]

Comment: That looks like the correct "double wall" style of pipe, especially if it doesn't get too hot.  I don't know what code says about clearances, so I'll let someone else answer, but at least it looks like you're on the right track.

Comment: Just had to follow code to put a double-wall pipe through a roof - the pipe needed surrounding by concrete to the wood and it looks so similar to what you show except we had to deal with an angle so the plate with a hole has as oval hole.

Answer (score 1):

### Depends on what the manufacturers specifications say.

For the particular doublewall insulated chimney (not "stovepipe" which is singlewall) I last had to work with, clearance to combustables was 2" from the pipe wall. The deformations at the joint appear to be consistent with what you have being double or triple wall insulated chimney, not stovepipe.

Stovepipe (singlewall) typically needs at least 18" clearance to combustibles, as it may get red-hot in the event of an excessive fire in the stove, or a chimney fire in the pipe.

Since the part shown is intended for framing support it's typically safe to have wood where the sheet screws in for support.

But the manufacturers specs (for the exact pipe and accessories you are actually working with) is what rules. You can almost certainly find out who that is by carefully examining the pipes (the info will be stamped into every piece, in my experience.) Then you should be able to look up the installation manual for the pipe and support piece.